# How to open a folder under a .Zip file In Unix

Tags: shell, unix, unzip

how to open a folder under .zip file using UNIX shell scripting.

Below Syntax is the hierarchy of zip file :

```
ZipFileName--> Test.Zip --> 01072014(folder name like today date)--> test.txt, *.tif
```

After unzip of Test.zip i want to open folder location(01072014) ?

Comment: For your OS, find a package named `unzip`. And what does this have to do with Java?

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg date +'%m%d%y' this command give 010714 but i want 01072014 output ?

Comment: Have you tried `man date`?

Comment: Hi,I would suggest that prior to zipping up the file, a directory is already set. This will avoid the dynamic+random folder naming.

Comment: Depends on what "opening" a folder (directory) means. Do you want to `cd` into it, open it in a GUI file manager, or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Q: How to open a folder under a .zip file using Unix shell scripting?

A: Use ["gzip"](http://linux.die.net/man/1/gzip), extract to a temp directory, then ["cd"](http://www.lehman.cuny.edu/cgi-bin/man-cgi?cd+1) into that directory.

NOTE:
This is *exactly* what happens when you open a .zip file using Windows Explorer - it extracts the contents of the .zip file into a temporary directory under your user profile.

Comment: The `gzip` commands only uncompresses GZIP-compressed files (typically with a file-ending of `.gz`), have nothing to do with ZIP *archives*.

Comment: @Foggy Day How to give dynamically name of the folder(like 01072014).Ex cd todaydate

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open **.gz** file without extracting then you can use **zcat** command.

Suppose you have **Test.gz** file then you can use

```
zcat Test.gz
```

Please ignore if i am not understanding the question correctly.